# trying to redirect all traffic from EC2 to container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, routes, containers

I have two EC2 instances. One of instance is running an app to in real time modify traffic (https://github.com/shramos/polymorph). But Polymorph deploys an container to work. So I need to redirect all traffic from EC2(172.31.46.198) who reach EC2(172.31.35.173) to container(10.24.0.2) to modify and intercept all traffic. 
 
I've been trying with potables but it doesnt work or I didn't properly.
 
Hope getting some help! Thanks all.

Comment: Do you have a load balancer over EC2(172.31.46.198) ?

Comment: @Rahuljuneja-DevOps no i dont

Comment: So did you put elastic Ip or public ip as A record ?

Comment: @Rahuljuneja-DevOps I tried both

Comment: Can you define your current routing